# Checking for incoming UDP packets and stdin simultaneously

Tags: java, sockets, input

I would like to listen both for incoming UDP packets and also for the user IO on my client side. So if the client enters something through the command line, I want to capture that and send a UDP packet while also checking for incoming UDP packets from the server. In C I can do this very easily using `select()`. I looked it into selectors but couldn't figure out how to do it on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is with two threads, one reading from `System.in` and the other reading from the `DatagramSocket.` The socket needs to be accessible to both threads so that the `System.in` thread can write to it.